# Where can I find a free compiler for Windows Vista which works in Fullscreen mode?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, windows-vista

I need to know where i can get a free version of C and C++ compilers for Windows Vista. Many of the versions i have tried are not working in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Fullscreen mode??? A compiler never works in fullscreen mode, what kind of question should this be? What has a compiler to do with fullscreen mode, nothing! A compiler just compiles C/C++ code to machine code. If you can use fullscreen mode or not depends on the libs you use, not the compiler

Comment: What do you mean by 'fullscreen mode' - both of the current answers (MingGW and VS 2008 Expression Edition) are answers to the 'free c/c++ compilers for windows', what do you mean by 'fullscreen mode'?  Specifying that may help you get a better answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C compiler for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116368/c-compiler-for-windows)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic.

Answer (score 15):

Please take a look at [visual studio 2008 express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/).

It is a freeware IDE and compiler from Microsoft for C#, VB.Net, C++, SQL, and web.

The Express line is a lightweight version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 product.

I believe it has full screen support in the IDE.

See the [wikipedia page for further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express).

Comment: Can you use VS2008Express to compile into native C/C++ code? I thought the Express editions only went into the .NET bytecode.

Comment: Yes, Visual C++ 2008 Express can build both native and managed applications.

Comment: Yes, you can create native win32 apps. For more info on the C++ edition of VS2008 Express, check this out http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/

Comment: I would also add to this answer that can you can get the compiler alone for free with the Windows SDK. You do not have to use it with the IDE. Though that is how most people use it.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)? It's a command-line compiler. I don't have Vista, so I can't test it, but it should work.

Comment: MinGW allows you to use gcc uder windows alternatively try cygwin which should provide similar facilities.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Express 2008 if free.  It's lacking some specific features that might be a requirements for you.  You can check [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/).

I'm not sure what you mean by "not working in fullscreen mode".  Can you be more explicit about what you have tried and exactly how it hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying out the on of thew Microsoft Visual Express packages. http://www.microsoft.com/express/.

I found them very good for trying things out especially for a single developer who is not too concerned about deployment and getting a product to market.
I am not sure if it works for Vista but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the aforementioned MSVS and MinGW, you could try [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) and [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/). While MSVS, especially with Visual Assist (costs money), is quite a powerful and convenient tool, the other IDEs have the benefit of working with more OSes. And yes, they’re powerful and convenient, too.

*Update*: True, these are IDEs, not compilers. For C++ under MS Windows, they both use MinGW as the compiler. But it’s my understanding that it’s IDEs that the OP needs.

Comment: I believe Eclipse CDT required a C compiler and does not come with one. And unless things have changed, Code::Blocks uses MinGW. But both are very good IDEs, although I'm partial toward Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to see if they work on Vista.

http://nuwen.net/mingw.html#download (comes with Boost with all the libs already built)

http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/