# Create a C program in Windows

Tags: c

I want to create a small C program and I would like to use the Windows command prompt to compile and run it. Can anyone suggest to me how to install a C compiler that works with the command prompt and the way to use it? How do I install the compiler, compile the code and run the program?

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116368/c-compiler-for-windows

Comment: there's always the free borland compiler

Comment: thanxx for the replying,I can you send me the link to download this and I like to know how to compile and run using that??

Answer (score 3):

There's several compilers available for Windows. Two popular ones are [Microsoft Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/default.aspx) and [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Using Visual C++, you can compile a program like so:

```
cl /Femyprog.exe myprog.c
```

Using MinGW, you can compile a program like so:

```
gcc -o myprog.exe myprog.c
```

Comment: thanxx for replying,can't we use "ghc" to run c programe??

Comment: @123Ex: No, `ghc` is for Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

Download [Visual Studio Express 2010 C++](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP). From the File menu, choose New, then Project. Under Project Types, expand the tree view to Visual C++ -> General, then choose the template for Empty Project.  Give it a name and a location. Click OK. Type in some C code, then Build and Run it.

It's a fairly simple tool to use, so I'd recommend you just go ahead and try it out.

Comment: And here is a command line compile walk through: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx

Comment: thanxxx for the reply,Sounds like good one,But I want to do this in command prompt

Comment: When you run the program from Visual Studio as I described, it will be launched automatically within a command prompt window which will also close when your program exits. If you wish you could also run `cmd` and then `cd` to your project directory and run the `.exe` yourself that way.

Answer (score 1):

Most programmers don't use command prompts to compile very much any longer. We use IDE's instead, because they're a hell-of-a-lot more convenient. Having said that there's no reason why you can't use the command prompt to "manually" execute the compiler which underlies, say, Microsoft Visual Studio.

So... If I where you I'd start by downloading **Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express Edition** from [Uncle Bills Funny Farm](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP). Note that C++ IDE (and compiler, or course) supports the old ANSI-C language as well as C++... in fact C++ is a "superset" of ANSI-C.

Your other options are a bit limited on Windows. I believe that [GCC: GNU's C++ Compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/) works on Windows... but it's "got a few issues" which nobody is any particular hurry to fix, simply because by far the majority of the GNU boys are running Linux, and they sort-of look down on Windows as "an interesting experiment [which failed]".

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Thanxxx ,First I want to tell.I'm new to the C and don't know how to start,I would like to do it in first command prompt and then move to IDE,I appreciate your valuable suggestions,I will move to IDE when I know the basic things in C

Comment: That's IS a good approach. Doing these things manually initially gives you an understanding of what your IDE is doing for you "under the hood"... and when the IDE fails, you've got a hope of understanding the problem well enough to fix it, or atleast work-around it manually.