# Is there a framework that must be installed for the C programming language?

Tags: c, frameworks

Hello I was wondering if there was a C framework for windows? Like if someone wanted to run a C program on Windows would they have to download C?

Comment: Look up "libc" ("msvcrt" in Microsoft terms), perhaps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116368/c-compiler-for-windows

Comment: Erm, no, C is not an interpreted language, like Python.  Nor is it a language that requires an elaborate VM like Java or C#.  The user simply copies or downloads the EXE file, the one produced by a C compiler and linker on the dev's machine.  That dev might decide that more than one file is needed, typically when he uses a "framework" himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C programming language does require some runtime support libraries; however, these are included in all major OS distributions (both Windows and UNIX). So, you just need to compile a C program targetting the desired CPU instruction set (e.g. "x86" for Intel chips) and distribute the compiled output. You don't need the user to install a separate set of libraries.

That being said, most programs of a sufficiently large size do rely on third party libraries and data files to work. This is why there are installer applications that copy over not just a single file but an entire directory containing the executable as well as the various libraries and associated files that are required to make that program work.