# CLion and MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw, clion

I want to try and learn how to use the C language. Therefore, I downloaded CLion and MinGW as toolchain. When trying to install the compiler, it says "test CMake run finished with errors". 
Did anybody ever had this problem? What should I do? (At the end of the question- what's written when I click "more" when it says "error"). 
Or, if you know of any other programs I should download in order to work with C, I'll be happy to hear.
Thanks in advance.

When clicking "more" it says:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.3.5/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/׳ ׳•׳¢׳�/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build13533773436764788547/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_e4849/fast && C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_e4849.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4849.dir/build
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/ג‰¡ֿƒג‰¥ֿ†/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build13533773436764788547/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4849.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-8~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_e4849.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\Users\ג•«ֳ¡ג•«׳¥ג•«ֳ³ג•«ֲ¥\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build13533773436764788547\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\ג•«ֳ¡ג•«׳¥ג•«ֳ³ג•«ֲ¥\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build13533773436764788547\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_e4849.dir\build.make:65: CMakeFiles/cmTC_e4849.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/ג‰¡ֿƒג‰¥ֿ†/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build13533773436764788547/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:120: cmTC_e4849/fast] Error 2

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/׳ ׳•׳¢׳�/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build13533773436764788547/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/׳ ׳•׳¢׳�/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build13533773436764788547/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Error code: 1
```

Comment: All you need is a text editor, and a [tag:C] [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116368/c-compiler-for-windows). Or, alternatively, use online compilers such as [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

Comment: yeah I know I need a c compiler, but it doesn't worl for me and I don't know why...

Comment: Have you tried to move your project into some other directory, which doesn't contain unusual symbols (like **non-English letters**)?

Comment: Can you try running this from windows cmd: `C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe --version`? if it works properly we'll know more

Comment: The easiest way is probably installing Linux (Ubuntu?) on a VM on your windows PC ... Then install anything you want there ...

Comment: for an online course the online compiler is enough... I'll try your suggestions anyway though. thank you all!